# Nested tags in @if statement not recognized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code in a view. After I added @if (Model.Error) the compiler now complains there is an error since the param, call and afterinit are not closed. I tried putting in text tags to no avail. The thing is the code actually run just fine in the view as a regular razor script, it is when I try to pre-compile the view I get a build error.

```
@using Core.UI;
@using Core.ViewModels.SQLServer;
@model LinkedServerListData
@{
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    Layout = null;
}
<rows>
    <head>
            @if (Model.HasError)
            {
                <afterinit>
                    <call command="SetServerError">
                        <param>@(Model.ErrorMessage)</param>
                    </call>
                </afterinit>
            }
        <settings>
            <colwidth>%</colwidth>
        </settings>
        <column width="100" align="left" sort="server" type="ro" hidden="false" id="Server">
            <![CDATA[
            <div style="@Html.Raw(Grid.HEADER_STYLE_LEFT)">Linked Server Name</div>]]>
        </column>
    </head>
    @foreach (string sServer in Model.Servers)
    {
        <row id="@(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())">
            <cell><![CDATA[@Html.Raw(sServer)]]></cell>
        </row>
    }
</rows>
```

Here is an image of the errors if that helps:

[image: Razor syntax error]

Comment: Do you technically need the `@` in front of `Model.ErrorMessage` since you're already in the scope of the `@if` ?

Comment: Yeah, probably superfluous, however that is not flagged, good catch though. As you can see I already took it out in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have to masquerade your literals something like this, it's a game of whack-a-mole which ones needs it and which doesn't, really odd and random behavior.

```
    @:<afterInit>
        @:<call command="SetServerError">
            @:<param>Model.ErrorMessage </param>
        @:</call>
    @:</afterInit>
```

I also found that some tags like  are auto-closed and by removing the end tag it minimizes confusion and @: are not needed in many cases.

```
    @if (Model.GridFilterFields.Length > 0)
    {
        <call command="SetFilters">
             <param>@MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.GridFilterFields)
             <param>@MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.GridFilterValues)
        </call>
    }
```